# Issue in Access file for Apache SVN over ubuntu 16

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn

I had installed Apache SVN over Ubuntu 16 . in which i am trying to put access base restriction for different path by AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/net location.
 hear i am facing issue for [/]  groups are getting restricted but apart from this location any path is not getting restricted inspite of trying multiple combination in access file.

```
Server.conf
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /svn/repos/
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn_serve.conf
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "MITS"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svnpasswd
  Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

Access file

```
[groups]
admins=svnnet
designers=designer1
[/]
@admins=r
[/svn/net]
@designers=r
@admins=rw
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some time i found out the mistake i was doing in. The bellow config file after giving repo name remaining path should be the folders you created nt starting from source folder.

Access file

```
[groups]
admins=svnnet
designers=designer1
[/]
@admins=r
[svn:/net]
@designers=r
@admins=rw
```